# (javascript or/and datejs)Trying to calculate two dates intervals total salary. when start date and end date has some fraction days of month

Tags: javascript, datejs

****Salary type monthly.****

```
var getDiffDatesSalary = function days_between(date1,date2, monthlyBasic) {
        var dateObj1 = new Date(date1);
        var month1 = dateObj1.getMonth(); //months from 1-12
        var day1 = dateObj1.getDate();
        var year1 = dateObj1.getFullYear();
        var daysInMonth1 = Date.getDaysInMonth(year1, month1);

        var dateObj2 = new Date(date2);
        var month2 = dateObj2.getMonth(); //months from 0-11
        var day2 = dateObj2.getDate();// days from 1
        var year2 = dateObj2.getFullYear();
        var daysInMonth2 = Date.getDaysInMonth(year2, month2);

        var date1FractionDays = daysInMonth1 - day1;
        var date2FractionDays = daysInMonth2 - day2;
        var newDate1, newDate2;
        if(day1 > 1){
            var perDaySalary1 = monthlyBasic / daysInMonth1;
            var thisMonthFarctionDaysSalaryForDate1 = perDaySalary1 * date1FractionDays;
            month1 += 1; // after calculate fraction this month basic, round month from next
            newDate1 = new Date(year1,month1);
        }
        if(day2 !== daysInMonth2){
           var perDaySalary2 = monthlyBasic / daysInMonth2;
           var thisMonthFarctionDaysSalaryForDate2 = perDaySalary2 * day2;
            month2 -= 1; //after calculate fraction this month basic, round month from previous
            newDate2 = new Date(year2,month2);
        }

       // i want to calculate totalSalaryamount of date ranges
        // var totalFractionDaysSalary = thisMonthFarctionDaysSalaryForDate1 + thisMonthFarctionDaysSalaryForDate2;
        // var totalMonthsSalay = roundMonths * monthlyBasic;
        // var totalSalaryamount = totalFractionDaysSalary + totalMonthsSalay;

    };
```

**

result = thisMonthFarctionDaysSalaryForDate1 + thisMonthFarctionDaysSalaryForDate2 + (roundMonths * monthlyBasic)

result will be   getDiffDatesSalary("2016/01/15","2016/03/25", 1000);

516.13+806.45 + 1000 // total: 2322.58

Or/And     getDiffDatesSalary("2015/01/15","2016/03/25", 1000) ;

516.13+806.45 + (1000 * 13) // total: 14322.58

Or/And     getDiffDatesSalary("2016/01/01","2016/02/29", 1000);

1000* 2 // 2000

**

Comment: try to use [`momentjs'](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: I need help to correct this function. I have tried but can't.. Thanks Zamboney

Comment: is the same day one day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to split the task in two sections:

1. Get total days
2. Calculate salary.

This proposal uses the difference between years, months and days and makes a correction if the day difference is negative. Same day means one day.

```js
function getDays(date1, date2) {
    var date1Obj = new Date(date1),
        date2Obj = new Date(date2),
        totalYear = date2Obj.getFullYear() - date1Obj.getFullYear(),
        totalMonth = date2Obj.getMonth() - date1Obj.getMonth(),
        totalDay = date2Obj.getDate() - date1Obj.getDate() + 1;

    if (totalDay < 0) {
        totalMonth--;
        totalDay += new Date(date1Obj.getFullYear(), date1Obj.getMonth(), 0).getDate();
    }

    return 360 * totalYear + 30 * totalMonth + totalDay;
}

function getDiffDatesSalary(date1, date2, salaryPerMonth) {
    return getDays(date1, date2) * salaryPerMonth / 30;
}

document.write(getDiffDatesSalary("2016/01/15", "2016/03/25", 1000) + '<br>');
document.write(getDiffDatesSalary("2016/01/31", "2016/02/15", 1000) + '<br>');
document.write(getDiffDatesSalary("2016/03/20", "2016/03/20", 3000) + '<br>');
```

Comment: Thanks for a great idea

Comment: function getDiffDatesSalary(date1, date2, salaryPerMonth) {
    return getDays(date1, date2) * salaryPerMonth / 30;
}

Comment: Its not showing exact result.. because each month is not 30 days. like Feb 29. Jan 31, Apr 30.... If monthly 1000 and date1 is 15/01 then 16 days salary will be (1000/31 )* 16. and if date1 is 15/02 then 14 days salary will be (1000/29)* 14 .   reverse as for date2  like 12/02  then 12 days salary will be calculate.

Comment: i think about that. please supply some more dates and answer, if the same date return one day or zero.

Comment: if date1 is same as date2 e.i 15/01   then result will be (1000/31) * 1 . Because the employee worked 1 day in a month so will get 1 day salary. if date1 15/01/2016 and date2 15/04/2016 then result will be: days_salary_for_date1 =(1000/31) * 16 and days_salary_for_date2= (1000/30)* 15 and round_months_salary=(1000*2)  .  finally result will be (days_salary_for_date1 + days_salary_for_date2 + round_months_salary)...

Comment: ah, i get it, you need exact days of the month and pay exact days.

Answer (score 0):

## I got the answer of my question. If anyone need or improve this answer. Here is the working codes:

```
var getDiffDatesSalary = function days_between(date1,date2, monthlyBasic) {
    var dateObj1 = new Date(date1);
    var month1 = dateObj1.getMonth(); //months from 0-11
    var day1 = dateObj1.getDate();
    var year1 = dateObj1.getFullYear();
    var daysInMonth1 = Date.getDaysInMonth(year1, month1);

    var dateObj2 = new Date(date2);
    var month2 = dateObj2.getMonth(); //months from 0-11
    var day2 = dateObj2.getDate();// days from 1
    var year2 = dateObj2.getFullYear();
    var daysInMonth2 = Date.getDaysInMonth(year2, month2);
    //get number of months in two different dates;
    var diffMonths = parseInt(diffInMonths(date2,date1)) +1; //from 1-12

    var date1FractionDays = daysInMonth1 - day1; //  date1 fraction days
    var date2FractionDays = daysInMonth2 - day2; //  date2 fraction days
    var totalFractionDaysSalary= 0, fractionMonthsCount = 0, thisMonthFarctionDaysSalaryForDate1 = 0, thisMonthFarctionDaysSalaryForDate2 =0; //reset as 0;
    //when date1: day start from 01, no fraction start of the month. Otherwise calculate salary for fraction days
    if(day1 > 1){
        var perDaySalary1 = monthlyBasic / daysInMonth1;
        thisMonthFarctionDaysSalaryForDate1 = perDaySalary1 * date1FractionDays;
        fractionMonthsCount +=1;
    }
    //when date2: day end  === end Of the Month, no fraction. Otherwise calculate salary for fraction days
    if(day2 !== daysInMonth2){
       var perDaySalary2 = monthlyBasic / daysInMonth2;
        thisMonthFarctionDaysSalaryForDate2 = perDaySalary2 * day2;
        fractionMonthsCount +=1;
    }
    // both date1 date2 fraction days salary sum
    totalFractionDaysSalary = thisMonthFarctionDaysSalaryForDate1 + thisMonthFarctionDaysSalaryForDate2;
    var roundMonthsForSalary = diffMonths - fractionMonthsCount; // after less round month calculate
    // if user do wrong reset as 0. because negative month not possible
    if (roundMonthsForSalary < 0){
        roundMonthsForSalary = 0;
    }
    // round month salary calculation
    var totalSalaryForRoundMonths = roundMonthsForSalary * monthlyBasic;
// finally fraction days and round month sum to get return result.
return totalFractionDaysSalary + totalSalaryForRoundMonths;

};
// get number of months in two different dates
function diffInMonths(to,from){
    var months = to.getMonth() - from.getMonth() + (12 * (to.getFullYear() - from.getFullYear()));

    if(to.getDate() < from.getDate()){
        var newFrom = new Date(to.getFullYear(),to.getMonth(),from.getDate());
        if (to < newFrom  && to.getMonth() == newFrom.getMonth() && to.getYear() %4 != 0){
            months--;
        }
    }

    return months;
};
```